# Is it possible to have a fallback widget for a custom field widget?

Tags: 7, entities

There's a similar question asked here: [Use multiple widget types for one field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78807/use-multiple-widget-types-for-one-field) but I was unable to reinstate the question with mine.

I have created a custom field widget with extended capabilities for authenticated users for a field. However the widget strongly relies on the person having a registered user account in the system, but I'd still like anonymous users to be able to input values for the field with the default widget. And to think of it, admins would have more use of the default one aswell.

The field is a customer_profile_reference field, so just rendering another type of field wouldn't work, I suppose (like text field instead).

Is there a way to fall back on the default widget with it's own validation when my custom widget has allready been initiated by being defined as the widget for the field in the UI? Basically I wish for an end result, where my widget would stay untouched if user is anonymous or has admin role, and another one is used.

Appreciate all and any help,

Alari

Comment: The other question you've linked to has the correct answer, where exactly are you stuck implementing it?

Comment: I'm not sure how or where would I implement it. Can I somehow do this in the custom widget module file, so that at the time the new widget has allready been called for I could still direct to use the other widget, or do I have to create a separate module?

Comment: Why not try it and see? It'll only take a minute, and save you waiting for someone to respond here.

Comment: May I ask if it's possible without using the hook, to do it within the widget initialisation? And even more if I can some how call for the default widget, but also add an element from my custom widget?

Comment: I can't imagine there's a way to do it without a hook that doesn't involve editing core code in some way. I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, sorry